# PHP Regex for 3 digit number (exactly) starting with 6

Tags: php, regex

I am trying write a PHP regex to find numbers only that are exactly 3 digits long and start with a 6.  So there should be no other symbols - just a 3-digit number.  I know

```
^6
```

will validate if it leads with a 6 and the following will validate it is exactly 3 digits long

```
^\d{3}$
```

but I can't find a way to combine these two expressions together into a single regex.  Anyone know how I can combine the expressions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are close :), now you just need to make 6 part of the expression and allow 2 digits after that 6:

```
^6\d{2}$
```

Should be what you are looking for